# Why cannot toggle the link to be visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried hard the following piece of code but still not working. The idea is to show a link once the file is selected to allow the file to be removed (or deselected). I want to solve the puzzle why the link does not show as it should. Thank you so much for the help!

For the info, I also tried "css", "show" and "hide". None works.

```
<html>

<script>
function removeFile()
{
  var input = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");
  input.value = input.defaultValue;
  refreshForm();
  return false;
}

function refreshForm() 
{
  var input = document.getElementById("fileToUpload");

  if (input.files.length > 0)
  {
    $("#upack-form > #remove-lnk").attr("visibility", "visible");
  }
  else
  {
    $("#upack-form > #remove-lnk").attr("visibility", "hidden");
  }
}
</script>

<div class="package">
  <form id="upack-form" action="/update_package" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <label>
      <input id="fileToUpload" type="file" name="file" style="width: 280px; overflow: hidden;" single onChange="refreshForm();" />
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </label>
    <a id="remove-lnk" style="visibility: hidden;" onclick="return removeFile();">remove</a>
  </form>
</div>

</html>
```

EDIT:

I found the difference of moving the hyper link inside the "label". In such case, it does not work.

Comment: check the browser console for errors..

Comment: Because you are not including jQuery, check your console for errors, you should be getting a `$ is not defined` or similar error, [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/dk3espd2/) when you do and use css instead of attr

Comment: Just as an FYI:  Your functions should include the `{` on the same line as the function declaration.  If it isn't this can cause issues. `function (){` .  It's not common but it can happen... better safe than sorry.

Comment: @GaryStorey, what issues would that be? The placement of the braces is merely for readability, and even that is in the eye of the beholder as some think its more readable the way OP has instead of egyption style. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/should-curly-braces-appear-on-their-own-line

Comment: @PatrickEvans if he's in Chrome, the $ operator defaults to the command line API, so he wasn't getting an error.

Comment: @amenadiel, no it doesn't unless its some setting: http://jsfiddle.net/pgdu8uLn/, causes me to have a `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: @PatrickEvans See this link. http://encosia.com/in-javascript-curly-brace-placement-matters-an-example/

Comment: I stand corrected, didn't even think of that

Comment: TIL what was that K&R setting in my jshint configuration :)

Comment: @GaryStorey thanks for sharing, didn't even think about that.

Comment: No problem.  I got hit with it a long time ago.  Just want to prevent it from happening to someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visibility is not an attribute, it's a style property

```
if (input.files.length > 0)
  {
    $("#upack-form > #remove-lnk").css("visibility", "visible");
  }
  else
  {
    $("#upack-form > #remove-lnk").css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
```

PD: As I told you in my comment, I noticed you weren't including jQuery, so I did. Now, [here's the working demo](http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/7bd9b9df91bb108f10c9)

Comment: since you are using jQuery operators, I assumed you had jQuery in your code, but it seems you haven't.

Comment: Did you even read his response? This will work fine as long as you include jQuery. Kinda hard to get jQuery functions to work if you don't load the jQuery library.

Comment: It doesn't matter when the comment came, at no point in time did your answer reflect the same code that the OP had already tried, so for them to claim that they already tried what you were suggesting implies that they did not read your answer.

Comment: Please check my recent edit. The hyperlink is actually inside the label. Then it does not work (even css). The missing of jquery is not relevant. Sorry for that.

Comment: if the link is inside the label, then a direct descendant selector ```>``` will not work. Just remove it to target any descendant with id #remove-lnk

Comment: @amenadiel, Thanks for the help! BTW, if I want to add some delay to show or hide, Is it like "...show/hide(500).css(...)". I tried, but not working well. Thanks.